# Watch Hallmark Channel on my laptop?

Tags: tv

I would like to watch the Hallmark Channel on my laptop computer, but Hallmark says it requires Windows to operate.

Does Linux software exist to be able to stream Hallmark TV w/Ubuntu?

I've run across other movie and TV services who say the same thing.

This is NOT for connecting to a TV screen, Roku, etc. This is for watching directly on my Lenovo Thinkpad w/Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you know how one watches Hallmark channel on Windows? Can you play in a web-browser or do you need a separate application?